# position: absolute styling only works if I use pos: absolute

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm so confused by this, you can see that it works with `pos: absolute;` but not with `position: absolute;`

What is the meaning of this?

https://jsfiddle.net/aasr169k/

```css
#about {
    background-color: #FFF0F4;
    padding: 200px 100px;

    .chair-drawing-container {
        border: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
        height: 400px;
        text-align: center;

        [href*="localhost"] {
            position: relative;

            &:before {
                pos: absolute;
                right: 100%;
                top: 25%;
                width: 80%;
                height: 30%;
                border-left: solid rgba(50,50,50,1) 8px;
                border-right: solid rgba(50,50,50,1) 8px;
                content: "";
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-8 chair-drawing-container">
                <a href="localhost"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `pos:absolute;` is not valid and therefore, most likely, **ignored** when rendering.

Comment: Assigning pos : absolute; means you are not assigning any position, even by removing that you will get same result.Because there is nothing like pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your `pos: absolute;` is not working, then if you try to use `position: absolute;` the design are change, that is the real effect of `position: absolute;` to your design. try to remove the `pos: absolute;` and run again, you will see, it is same happen, so thats mean your position not set as absolute.